# Pacote para validações por serviço

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer

Estou a desenvolver um projeto de grandes dimensões com Laravel e preciso de validar os meus dados. Inicialmente tinha pensado usar o Ardent, mas este não é compatível/aconselhável para quem usa o padrão repositório.

Por isso vou ter que fazer as validações por serviços. 
Aconselham algum pacote especifico?

Comment: Bem-vindo, Miguel. Você tem requisitos mais específicos? Perguntar o que os outros aconselham não funciona bem aqui, pois cada um dará sua opinião e vai ficar difícil eleger uma como correta. Sugiro que leia [Devemos aceitar questões de recomendação](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57/devemos-aceitar-questoes-de-recomendacao) e [Good subjective, bad subjective](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective).

Comment: @bfavaretto o unico requisito é de permitir a validação como serviços e não através de modelos com o Ardent.

Answer (score 1):

Implementando validação como serviço:

Não conheço um pacote, desconfio que ainda não existe.

Mas há um par de artigos que contêm exatamente o que você quer:

http://culttt.com/2013/07/29/creating-laravel-4-validation-services/
http://culttt.com/2014/01/13/advanced-validation-service-laravel-4/

Com a solução apresentada, você especifica as suas regras de validação assim:

```
<?php namespace App\Service\Validation\Laravel;

use App\Service\Validation\ValidableInterface;

class UserCreateValidator extends LaravelValidator implements ValidableInterface {

  /**
   * Validação para criar um novo User
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $rules = array(
    'username' => 'required|min:2',
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'password' => 'required'
  );

}
```

A classe `UserCreateValidator` herda a funcionalidade básica da classe `AbstractValidator`, a funcionalidade específica do Laravel para rodar testes de validação da classe `LaravelValidator` e por fim cada classe filha finaliza a implementação com as regras especificamente requeridas. A implementação de `ValidableInterface` assegura que a classe cumpra os requerimentos do contrato.